# Sharepoint Online REST API System.UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to get SiteGroup/Users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying get SiteGroup/Users from Sharepoint Online, by calling this REST API:
/_api/web?$expand=webs,lists,AllProperties,ThemeInfo,SiteUsers,SiteGroups,SiteGroups/Users,RoleDefinitions&$select=*

While on some customers sharepoint sites it's works fine , on other it's failing with :

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message": 
{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform 
this action or access this resource."}}}
```

When I remove SiteGroups/Users it's working fine, but I need SiteGroups/Users. In both cases user that I'm accessing with is Site collection Admin. So, I'm trying to understand what can be difference between admins that in one case works fine but in another not.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is Occur because you have done app registration on wrong url for example if your SharePoint File base Url is  **https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/yourfoldername**
then Use this url for App registration **https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/yourfoldername/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx** not this **https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx**.

You could refer to this article to register you app for rest API:
https://anoopt.medium.com/accessing-sharepoint-data-using-postman-sharepoint-rest-api-76b70630bcbf

Comment: How this is related to app registration ? I didn't said a word about OAuth. It's basic auth (username and password) in my case